# In selenium webdriver when I add parameter and run the progrmme below error is showing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
package webdriver3;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestingAmazon {

    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass

    public void setUp(){

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://google.co.in");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        openAmazon();
    }


    public void openAmazon(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lst-ib']")).sendKeys("Amazon india");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sblsbb']/button")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Amazon']")).click();
        hoverLogin();
    }


    public void hoverLogin(){
        Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
        WebElement mainmenu= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']/span[1]"));
        builder.moveToElement(mainmenu).build().perform();

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-flyout-ya-signin']/a/span")));
        WebElement submenu=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-flyout-ya-signin']/a/span"));
        submenu.click();
        Reporter.log("Done.....",true);
    }


    @Parameters({"userName","password"})
    @Test
    public void enterCreditial(String userName, String password){

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement loginbox= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ap_email']"));
        WebElement passwordbox= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='ap_password']"));
        WebElement signin= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='signInSubmit']"));
            if(loginbox.isDisplayed()){
                Reporter.log("You can enter log in name");
                loginbox.sendKeys(userName);
                    if(passwordbox.isDisplayed()){
                        Reporter.log("You can enter password");
                        passwordbox.sendKeys(password);
                            if(signin.isDisplayed()){
                                Reporter.log("You can signin");
                                signin.click();
                            }
                    }
            }
    }


    public void informationCommand(){
        String titletext=driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("Title is:" + titletext);

        String pageurl= driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("Page url:" + pageurl);

        String windowhandle= driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("Windowhandle:" + windowhandle);

        Set<String>windowhandles= driver.getWindowHandles();
        System.out.println("Windowhandles:" + windowhandles);
    }


    public void signout(){
        Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
        WebElement mainmenu= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-link-yourAccount']/span[1]"));
        builder.moveToElement(mainmenu).build().perform();

        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-item-signout']/span")));
        WebElement signout=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='nav-item-signout']/span"));
        signout.click();
        Reporter.log("Successfuly signout.......",true);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

When I run this programme using TestNG script, I get the following error:

> Parameter 'userName' is required by @Test on method enterCreditial but has not been marked @Optional or defined
>   in C:\Users\jahansalia\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1960767273\testng-customsuite.xml

Comment: I like feeding parameters to a test in from a DataProvider annotation because when you do it that way, you can get access to those parameters from the Before... annotated methods.  For example, a DataProvider can instantiate Capabilities and props for each test, and the BeforeMethod method can start the WebDriver for you before the actual Test method runs.  Thats something JUnit cant do.

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you are not using testng.xml

The list of variables used to fill the parameters of this method. These variables must be defined in your testng.xml file. For example

```
@Parameters({ "xmlPath" })
@Test
public void verifyXmlFile(String path) { ... }
```

and in testng.xml you need to give detail like this:

```
<parameter name="xmlPath" value="account.xml" />
```

Reference :-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm

Comment: It's working partially not working perfectly can you explain in details.

Comment: Run your sciprt by using testng.xml ... means right click on testng.xml and run as TestNg. try this .. I suppose that you have added the class path and parameter inside the testng.xml

Comment: Another thing is what do you mean by working partially .. can you explain what problem you are getting